# dot error when displaying the number in the text

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
return TextFormField(
      controller: _nameController,
      onChanged: (v) => _MyFormState.friendsList[widget.index] = v,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: '$widget.index .nci eleman'
      ),
      validator: (v){
        if(v.trim().isEmpty) return 'kutulara eleman girişi yapınız';
        return null;
      },
    );
```

With the above code
'$widget.index .nci eleman'
in a post.
I want to get the 'widget.index' number.

But does not allow this.

In other languages

```
'$widget.\index'
```

did not work in the structure.

So how can I get data from a class using a dot with the $ keyword in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use curly braces like this:

```
 InputDecoration(
    hintText: '${widget.index} .nci eleman'
  ),
```

Here is more about [string interpolation](https://shailen.github.io/blog/2012/11/14/dart-string-interpolation/) in Dart.